# Total number of $4$ digit numbers whose product of digits is $72$

Tags: combinatorics

> Total number of $4$ digit numbers whose product of digits is $72$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Here the possible factor of $72 = 2^{3}\cdot 3^2$

Now here we divide $2^3\cdot 3^3$ into product of $4$ numbers

Like $1\cdot 1\cdot 8\cdot 9$

and $1\cdot 2\cdot 4\cdot 9$

and $1\cdot 2\cdot 6\cdot 6$

and $1\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 6$

and $1\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 8$

and $2\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 6$

and $2\cdot 2 \cdot 2\cdot 9$

So arrangement of these numbers is $$\frac{4!}{2!}+4!+\frac{4!}{2!}+4!+\frac{4!}{2!}+\frac{4!}{2!}+\frac{4!}{3!} = 12+12+12+24+24+12+4=100$$

But answer given is $=112$

So Where i have make mistake, Is there is any other better method,

Then plz explain here

Thanks

Comment: $72=2^3\cdot 3^2$, not $2^3\cdot 3^3$.

Comment: Maybe its $72=2^3.3^2$

Comment: Yes user236182,Archis Welankar, i have made mistake, Thanks

Comment: You forgot to fix the same error on the next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where have I made a mistake?

- You forgot to count the number of permutations of $[2,3,3,4]$
- You miscounted the number of permutations of $[2,2,3,6]$ as $\frac{4!}{3!}$

Answer (score 3):

$1\cdot 1\cdot 8\cdot 9$

and $1\cdot 2\cdot 4\cdot 9$

and $1\cdot 2\cdot 6\cdot 6$

and $1\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 6$

and $1\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 8$

and $2\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 6$

and $2\cdot 2 \cdot 2\cdot 9$

and $2\cdot 3 \cdot 3\cdot 4$

So arrangement of these numbers is $$\frac{4!}{2!}+4!+\frac{4!}{2!}+4!+\frac{4!}{2!}+\frac{4!}{2!}+\frac{4!}{3!}+\frac{4!}{2!} = 12+12+12+24+24+12+4+12=112$$